# Grouping morphed models by model type after mapToGroups()

Tags: php, laravel, collections

When featuring content on my application, I need to handle different types of content models like `Music` and `Author`. To do this, I have a Feature model and FeaturableTrait (containing the `morphTo()` relation which I added to the Featurable models.

My feature model looks like this:

```
class Feature extends BaseModel
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'featurable_id', 'featurable_type'];

    /**
     * Get all of the owning featurable models.
     */
    public function featurable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

To complicate things a little further, I have different sub-sections within my featured section like "Spotlight", "Editor's Choice", "Trending" etc.

In my `FeatureController`, I need to pull all the records from the `features` table, map them to groups based on the `name` attribute, then group the resulting groups again by `featurable_type` so that the app can distinguish them in the UI.

So far, I've done:

```
// Get the records from the database and eager load the featurable model

$features = Feature::with(['featurable'])
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->orderBy('featurable_type')
    ->get();

// Separate into collection groups based on the feature sub-section
$features = $features->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [$item['name'] => $item['featurable']];
});

// Do something to separate the featurable models in each subsection by model type

// Return the result
    return $features;
```

I want the result to have a collection of featured sections, which inside them have a separate collection for each `featurable_type` differentiating between the `Music` and `Artist` models so that I can send each model to it's appropriate transformer.

Been stuck on this for a day and a half now, so if anyone can give me some inspiration with collection kung-fu, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `eachSpread` to drill down and further group the collections:

```
$features = $features->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [$item['name'] => $item['featurable']];
})->eachSpread(function ($name, $collection) {
    return [$name => $collection->mapToGroupsfunction ($item, $key) {
        return [$item['featurable_type'] => $item];
    })];
});
```